# How to set up SSL?HTTPs in asp.net

Tags: c#

How do you setup asp.net web application for SSL? 
Do I need to publish to the IIS or just copy the whole folder with the 3 folder(BAL,DAL,FV)inside wwwroot?
I have a self-sign cert. 
I am using Visual Studio 2010 and IIS 7.0. My database is SQL Server express.
I have tried many methods but all do not include a Database. 
This is how do my 3 tier.

> DAL(Class Library)
>  BAL(Class Library)
>  FV(WebApplication)

They are not in the same folder but they are in the same solution
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

You setup SSL from within IIS, not in the application.

For more instructions follow http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/144/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis/

Specifically the part where it says "IIS Manager"